# Virtual method of copy of Pointer not working

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, inheritance

I'm having a problem with Overriding methods on C++

First, everything worked just fine, then, I made some changes to keep the code more "organized" and to share on GitHub.

After doing some OO changes, to facilitate and make it easier to understand, my code stopped working, and because of a very weird thing.

`ViewGroup` is a class that extends `View`, and has the method HitTest override from `View`.

So, basicaly: if I call hitTest, I must be running on the ViewGroup (if it's a ViewGroup), or on a View;

Thats ok, I put the `virtual` on my method, and if I DIRECLY run on my ViewGroup, it in fact runs the hitTest from ViewGroup,

but, if I create a new pointer, and try to run, it doesen't runs hitTest on ViewGroup anymore, it runs on View. To facilitate the understanding:

```
ViewGroup *v = new ViewGroup();

View *t = v;

v->hitTest(100,100); // Runs on ViewGroup (OK)
t->hitTest(100,100); // Runs on View (NOT OK)
```

**UPDATE:**

> ViewGroup.h: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3lqbm73qlxds3i/ViewGroup.h
>
> ViewGroup.cpp: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxbqsh6ol430x4p/ViewGroup.cpp
>
> View.h: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tcrb75dmx3v6pgq/View.h
>
> View.cpp: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4sb82d6thqz34od/View.cpp

**UPDATE 2:**

The problem was caused by a dumb mistake on the declaration of the methods.
One, was declared as `hitTest(int x, int y)` and the other, `hitTest(long x, long y)`.

It happend while "cleaning"  and improving the code.

But, it's very weird, since it was working before I copied the object, and after copying, not any more...

Comment: I've updated @JimBalter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signatures of the two-argument versions of hitTest are different. If you're coding to C++11, use the override keyword for all overrides of virtual functions ... it will spare you this sort of grief.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would never see it (in the next 72hours) =]

Comment: I'd suggest to use `override` keyword from C++11. It will throw an error if method doesn't override anything([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=db3e609d635bb06ba455c1e701572318-7f4bc2c90970fdf19c48ebf8cc2bae3f)).

Comment: Just waiting more 2 minutes =]

Comment: @soon I was adding it while you were suggesting it.

Comment: How do I know if my version is 11+? I'm using the copiller given by Arduino

Comment: @IvanSeidel You could try the keyword and see if it accepts it ... even some pre-C++11 compilers do (which is where the keyword came from).

Comment: @JimBalter =/ View.h:103: error: expected ';' before 'override'

Comment: @IvanSeidel You'll have to wait for the future to arrive.

Comment: @IvanSeidel, it means, your compiler doesn't support C++11. But just keep in mind: you should use keyword `override` to avoid such kind of errors.

Comment: I'm waiting for it... I HATE dumb compilers! When you get used with Java, it's very sad to know "idiot" things can still make you loose 10 hours of your life

Comment: @IvanSeidel Consider C# ... it's one of several languages that gets override right, quite unlike C++ ... including C++11.

Comment: Well, I would if I could ^^ Unfortunaley, Arduino (microcontrollers) don't have support for such a "complex" languages, that's why I use C++ (And it's also a big advantage, since it's C++ and no just C) (There are microcontrollers with support for that, but it's not my case)